# OpenCv convert circle to polygon

Tags: c++, opencv, geometry, polygon

I was wondering if there is a way in OpenCv to convert an `circle` with a given radius to an `polygon` (e.g. pentagon or hexagon or something like this) ?

Circle is pretty easy:

```
 cv::circle(myMat, center_point, radius, colour, 2, 16);
```

and polygon is easy as well:

```
 cv::polylines(myMat, points, isClosed, colour, 2, 16);
```

My approach is the following:

```
int length = 150;
Point center_point(500, 500);

Point P1;
P1.x = (int)round(center_point.x + length * cos(0 * CV_PI / 180.0));
P1.y = (int)round(center_point.y + length * sin(0 * CV_PI / 180.0));

Point P2;
P2.x = (int)round(center_point.x + length * cos(45 * CV_PI / 180.0));
P2.y = (int)round(center_point.y + length * sin(45 * CV_PI / 180.0));

Point P3;
P3.x = (int)round(center_point.x + length * cos(90 * CV_PI / 180.0));
P3.y = (int)round(center_point.y + length * sin(90 * CV_PI / 180.0));

Point P4;
P4.x = (int)round(center_point.x + length * cos(135 * CV_PI / 180.0));
P4.y = (int)round(center_point.y + length * sin(135 * CV_PI / 180.0));

Point P5;
P5.x = (int)round(center_point.x + length * cos(180 * CV_PI / 180.0));
P5.y = (int)round(center_point.y + length * sin(180 * CV_PI / 180.0));

Point P6;
P6.x = (int)round(center_point.x + length * cos(225 * CV_PI / 180.0));
P6.y = (int)round(center_point.y + length * sin(225 * CV_PI / 180.0));  

Point P7;
P7.x = (int)round(center_point.x + length * cos(270 * CV_PI / 180.0));
P7.y = (int)round(center_point.y + length * sin(270 * CV_PI / 180.0));

Point P8;
P8.x = (int)round(center_point.x + length * cos(315 * CV_PI / 180.0));
P8.y = (int)round(center_point.y + length * sin(315 * CV_PI / 180.0));

cv::polylines(myMat, {P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8}, isClosed, colour, 2, 16);
```

which is working, but I was wondering if there is a more clever way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, more clever way does exist - use array and loops.

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
  P[i].x = (int)round(center_point.x + length * cos(i * 2 * CV_PI / N));
  P[i].y = (int)round(center_point.y + length * sin(i * 2 * CV_PI / N));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally I found a solution which contains not only Math Formular ...